# Bizzare nullref in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I have a small piece of C++ code that is making me insane.  Whenever it runs, it throws a null reference exception in a very unexpected place.

```
void CSoundHandle::SetTarget(CSound* sound)
{
  assert(_Target == nullptr);
  if (sound == nullptr) { return; }

  _Target = sound;

  // This works just fine.
  _Target->Play();

  // This is the code that throws the exception.  It doesn't seem possible, as
  // we should not be able to get here if 'sound' is null.
  _Target->Stop();
}
```

So what the heck is going on?  The message in the output window is:

```
this->_Target-> was nullptr.
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014
```

I have confirmed in disassembly that it is not taking place inside of the Stop function as well.  How is this possible?

EDIT:
The pointer for sound is indeed initialized, and 'this' and 'this->Target' are non-null.

EDIT 2:
I have somehow solved the problem by slightly changing the declaration of the Stop function:

```
// From this.
virtual void Stop();

// To this.
void Stop();
```

This seems especially odd since Play() is also virtual, but works without any trouble.  I can't say I've ever seen anything like this before.  There are no other functions named 'Stop' in the rest of the program, nor are there subclasses of CSound, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Sounds like `this` is null.

Comment: 'this' is not null.  Note the error message, and the fact that the rest of the code works.

Comment: Names starting with underscore-capital are reserved for the implementation; don't use such names.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You missed the `_Target = sound;` line.

Comment: Most likely, your ````sound```` pointer is not being initialized. Just because it isn't pointing at something of interest doesn't mean it is automatically ````nullptr````

Comment: @user2357112: I sure did!

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading location `0x00000014` implies you're trying to access a field located 0x14 bytes from the beginning of an object. The pointer to that object is set to null. So the problem is in the caller of your function: it passes a bad pointer to `sound`, which is neither null nor valid. This is why the null check in your function passes (0x14 isn't null), but you still crash.

Update:
The second edit to the question indicates the problem is in calling a virtual function. The null here is the virtual pointer then, and 0x14 is the offset of the `Stop` virtual function. The virtual pointer is set (in code generated by the compiler) during object construction, and should never point to 0. If it does, some part of the program is corrupting the object. An easy to detect case would be an attempt to reset the object, but memory corruptions (e.g., out-of-bound write to an array) could also cause this issue.

Comment: The pointer is valid, I can even call other functions on it.  See my edits.

Comment: Do those functions access `CSound` fields? if not, they don't access illegal addresses, hence complete successfully. But a debugger would immediately clear this point: is `_Target` pointing to 0x14 as the error message says or not? If it does now but didn't earlier, some other code is overriding it. Maybe try reverse debugging (which is a cool feature I never had a chance to try...).

Comment: @A.R.: You cannot *check* for undefined behaviour from within the program. You have to *prove* that your behaviour is well-defined from logical reasoning about your code.

Comment: Yes, both functions access fields within CSound.  _Target is a valid pointer, pointing to a real memory location.  Nothing is overriding it between calls to Play() and Stop()

Comment: @A.R. your second edit raises another option: maybe the virtual pointer of  `_Target` was overrun and set to 0 (did you `memset` the object?), and the 0x14 is the offset of the vtable entry. The call to `Play` may have worked because the compiler was able to avoid going through the vtable.

Comment: @eran :what might cause something like that to happen?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: See eran's comment for an example of useful feedback.

Comment: One possible reason is trying to initialize an object using memset, which zeros its fields but also the vpointer. Another reason is some memory corruption. Take a look at the vpointer (quick and dirty: `*(int*)_Target`). Is it 0? If so, you'll have to work your way back and find when that zero was set.

Comment: @eran:  Bingo!  The original sound was coming from an array that I was setting up with calloc, instead of just 'new CSound[count]'.  Using the second version has solved the problem :)  Thanks for actually taking the time to help with the issue instead of insisting that my analysis was incorrect.  I was able to learn something new because of it, and will be able to help others in the future.  If you write up an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @A.R.: Tools like ASAN and Valgrind are quite useful for analysing invalid accesses like this.